# How can I authenticate users present in my Azure AD without creating an Azure App (at App Registrations)?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, angular7, azure-authentication

I have an Azure AD app (at app registrations) using which I authenticate my users by obtaining the token. This requires the client ID as well as client secret mapped to the app. I do not want to create this app but want to authenticate the users present in my Active Directory.

Comment: as far as I know it is not possible :D. you will need an app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, to authenticate users with AAD you must register an app in AAD.
You don't need a secret for that though, if you redirect to login at Azure AD and then get a valid token as a response (your tenant, valid signature etc.) then the user logged in with a user in your AAD tenant.

Comment: Okay, thank you for clarifying that. Actually the app that I am developing will be hosted on a virtual machine. So I can't figure out how to authenticate the users that will be using it.

Comment: That depends what kind of app it is. Is it a command-line app? Is it a web app?

Comment: It is a Web App and being built on Angular 7.

Comment: So you host it on a VM and the users access it through an endpoint? Then you'd need MSAL.js in your app.

Comment: Thank you Juunas. It helped me a lot. Though I haven't completed the development, but I'm confident that I'll be able to do it as the direction you pointed me to, was helpful.